# Cascading count down fashion in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I'm working on a iOS project where i need to show the increased or decreased score in cascading count down fashion.

[image]

Here in the attached image score is decreasing from 15 to 10, so the animation will appear like a dropping effect starting from 15 and will go in order 14, 13, 12, 11 and then 10. Coming from the bottom reaches on to the top as shown in the image. hope you can see it clearly number 14 and 13 are visible.

I'm not sure if it is a kind of shadow effect or something else. Totally stuck. Please suggest how to achieve this task.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem using 3 `UILabel` on a single `UIView` and animate them with some interval. The process is as follows

Algorithm

1. Set the 2nd Label with the text(Score) and scale it to some value.
2. Set the 3rd Label With the next Score value.
3. Scale Down the 2nd label to 0(Identity) and place it to the position of 1st label.
4. Similarly scale up the 3rd label to the 2nd position. and move the 1st label to the last position.
5. Set the next score value to the 3rd label.
6. Repeat the steps 1 to 5 till the last score value. and stop the animation.

Here I'm adding my code.

```
-(void)animateForLabel:(UILabel *)scoreLabel
{
    if (shouldAnimate)
    {
        //I've placed 3 labels on a view. Object at index 2 will be on top
        UILabel *lbl1 = [[animationLayer subviews] objectAtIndex:2]; //Top label
        UILabel *lbl2 = [[animationLayer subviews] objectAtIndex:1]; //Middle Label
        UILabel *lbl3 = [[animationLayer subviews] objectAtIndex:0]; //Bottom Label

        lbl1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; //Setting first label to its original position
        [lbl1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, lbl1.frame.size.width, lbl1.frame.size.height)];

        //Setting View Position, This something you can set the Label's Superview position to their superview 
        [animationLayer setFrame:[self convertFrameForLabel:scoreLabel]];
        [lbl2 setCenter:CGPointMake(animationLayer.frame.size.width/2, lbl2.center.y)];
        [lbl3 setCenter:CGPointMake(animationLayer.frame.size.width/2, lbl3.center.y)];

        [self addTextToAnimationLabel:lbl1]; //Adding the new value to the the desired label
        [lbl1 setCenter:CGPointMake(animationLayer.frame.size.width/2, lbl1.center.y + 10)];
        lbl1.layer.opacity = 0.0; //Setting its opacity to zero so that it will look invisible.


        double durationInSeconds = 0.1;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:durationInSeconds delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
            [lbl1 setCenter:CGPointMake(lbl1.center.x, lbl1.center.y - 10)];
            lbl1.layer.opacity = 0.3; // Setting their opacity according to the need
            lbl2.layer.opacity = 0.6; // Same as above
            lbl3.layer.opacity = 0.8; // Same as above

            lbl3.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.2, 1.2);
            lbl2.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(lbl2.transform, 1.8, 1.8); // Setting scale so that the animation flow must be visible as curve shape

            lbl3.center = CGPointMake(lbl3.center.x, 7);
            lbl2.center = CGPointMake(lbl2.center.x, 30);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            NSLog(@"Complete animation");
            if ([scoreLabel isEqual:creatorScoreLbl])
                [self setWidthIfCreatorScoreChanged:[lbl3.text integerValue]];
            else
                [self setWidthIfOpponentScoreChanged:[lbl3.text integerValue]];
            [animationLayer insertSubview:lbl3 atIndex:2];
            if (![lbl3.text isEqualToString:@""] && [lbl3.text integerValue] == toScore)
            {
                shouldAnimate=NO;
                [audioService stopPlaying];
                [animationLayer removeFromSuperview];
            }
            else
            {
                [self animateForLabel:scoreLabel];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call the method again and again till the last value of the score